# How to show a map is a homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology

[image]

I have calculated two of the properties of homeomorphism. Where I have found the bijective mapping and showed that $f$ is continuous. However i am not sure how to show that $f^{-1}$ is continuous?

Comment: How did you show that your $f$ was continuous? Since $f$ is a bijection, you know $f^{-1}$; it just reverses what $f$ did. Then you can use the same technique to show that $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

Comment: i used the pre image to show that f is continuous so reversing this will prove that $f^{-1}$ is continuous?

Comment: Show your map is open: it sends open sets to open sets. This will be the same as checking the inverse is continuous.